# Nodejs Duplicate Fields

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using a POST route to post data on a user's progress. I'm looking for a way to check if theres duplicate fields when posting, so I don't post multiple results

My route:

```
api.post('/progress', (req, res) => {
    let progress = new Progress();
    progress.user_id = req.body.user_id;
    progress.level = req.body.level;

    progress.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({
            message: 'progress saved!'
        });
    });
});
```

My Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let progressSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: String,
  level: String,

});

var levels = mongoose.model('Progress', progressSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Progress', progressSchema);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose: detect if document inserted is a duplicate and if so, return the existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638982/mongoose-detect-if-document-inserted-is-a-duplicate-and-if-so-return-the-exist)

Comment: Can you tell us what the `Progress` object is?  I assume that is your data object that is helping you save your object.

Comment: I've added my model for reference to the "progress" @MindlessRouse

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MongoDB? If so, you can use mongoose module and add

unique: true,

to the field's attributes in your Progress schema. Check out the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, it unfortunately still allowed duplicates. I added the model in the question for reference @yakubori

Comment: Try it like this:

user_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },

Comment: Ok that actually did work! - how would you error handle this with the E11000, as far as in the POST request?  @yakubori

Comment: If I were you, I would look for that specific error code and return a more user-friendly message in res.send().